# Choosing between internal and production version of page

Tags: website-design, gui-design

I develop an administration interface of website. In "*live edit*" mode user can browse the website and edit pages (mostly texts). Website is presented in default production design to user and only small bar with close, save and revisions buttons is shown in the middle left of the screen. Users can save the page as Production version (and overwrite current page) or as Internal verion. There can be only one internal version which is shared among all the users.

**When user navigates to the page**

- should I display current Internal (if any) or Production version by default?
- how should I let user clearly know which version is currently viewing?
- how should I let user choose between versions?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Depends on your use case. If it's likely that a user will just want to see the page without making changes, then I'd prefer to minimize the chances that the page will go live by mistake: I'd make the users request the internal page explicitly by navigating to Edit mode. But if that's not a likely scenario and in most cases users will only want the page in order to edit it, then I think it's worthwhile to display the internal version by default (since that's the most up-to-date version, the one that gives real visibility into the most advanced version of the page).

The following layout should be an effective solution to your last two points.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f63fW7.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>